# Does disabling third party cookies protect a client against cross site request forgery attacks?

Tags: browser, security, csrf

Say that example.org uses cookies to authenticate users and it did not implement cross site request forgery protection. Is an example.org user that disabled third party cookies secured against CSRF attack (assuming that all sensitive requests to example.org require valid authentication cookie to be present)?  If this is not the case, can you give examples illustrating how evil.com can perform sensitive operations in a name of the example.org user?

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't see how the wiki page answers the question. The example given there (img src=http://bank.example.com/withdraw) would not work if a user disabled third party cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling third party cookies will only make the browser *reject cookies being set by third party sites*. So if you’re visiting a page from site *A* and there’s a resource requested from site *B*, your browser will reject any cookie that is not from site *A*.

But if there already are cookies for a third party site set, i.e. you have visited the third party site directly, the browser will send them along in a request. So if you’re visiting a page from site *A* and there is a resource requested from site *B*, your browser will send any cookies set for site *B* along.

This means, disabling third party cookies does not protect you against CSRF.

Comment: I remember there was an issue with iframe that blocking 3rd party cookies didn't allow csrf(ie had this on default). correct me if i'm wrong but i agree with you that 3rd party cookies aren't a protection from csrf (read my answer and comments) cheers.

Comment: @TheNewOne You are probably referring to *X-Frame-Options*. But that doesn’t prevent CSRF. It can only prevent that a server’s response is displayed in a frame on a third party page. But the forged request will already be sent.

Comment: you are right... so that means i need to change from blocking 3rd party cookies has almost no effect to has no effect at all :), i misunderstood that but by reading again the request really passes with the cookie in it.

Comment: Quick test shows that this is not the case at least with Firefox. Visit google.com, cookie is set, open Tools->Web Developer->Web Console. Go to http://xkcd.com, use the console to examine a GET reqeust for https://www.google.com/jsapi. Cookies are sent. Open Edit->Preferences->Privacy->Use custom settings for history, uncheck 'Accept third-part cookies'. Refresh xkcd.com, GET request to https://www.google.com/jsapi contains no cookies.

Comment: @JanWrobel CSRF does not need frames. They just make the attack less obvious.

Comment: @Gumbo Can you elaborate on what you mean? My comment was just explaining that in Firefox, when you disable third party cookies, cookies are not included in cross domain requests (at least simple GETs). This applies also to cookies that are already set. The comment was not related to frames.

Comment: @JanWrobel Nonetheless, CSRF requests do not need to be triggered in a context where their sites are treated as third party. Thus disabling third party cookies has no effect.

Comment: @Gumbo, what do you mean "CSRF requests do not need to be triggered in a context ..." -- by definition CSRF is cross site attack, so if disabling the cookies in Firefox prevents them from sending, that should prevent CSRF, right? But it would still allow Same Site Request Forgery. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand how *third party cookies* work - 
the most common explanations include ads so I would do the same.

when you visit a site `somesite.com` and it has a graphic ad in it.

when the site makes the request to the ad (assuming the ad is from ads.com) so it asks `ads.com` to load the ad and it allows it to store a cookie. that cookie can be used to build a profile on you, that's why *third party cookies* sometimes called *tracking cookies*.

By blocking third party cookies your browser doesn't allow `ads.com` (in our example) to store a cookie (but the ad would still be shown).

Therefore, let's assume you have an open session with `mymail.com`, and you enter `evil.com`, `evil.com` has an image that requests an operation from `mymail.com`, for instance *img src=mymail.com/deleteAll*.

the browser makes a request to this site but because you have an open session and no protection against csrf on `mymail.com`, the request would pass with the cookie you already have with `mymail.com` because you have a session with it.

I would recommend to read [OWASP's csrf prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for some further reading.

Comment: My understanding is that when you visit evil.com, cookie associated with mymail.com is considered a third party cookie even if it was set as a first party cookie. Such cookie won't be included in requests to mymail.com from evil.com if third party cookies are disabled. Basically, which cookies are third party depends on  context. This writing confirms this: http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/third-party-cookies/ Is this incorrect?

Comment: what do you mean by 'a link would pass this protection'? Are you sure that when third party cookies are disabled, cookies are sent with a form submissions to a different origin site or is this just a speculation?

Comment: "In February 2012 a researcher at Stanford University, Jonathan Mayer, noted how a well-known quirk in Safari's blocking of third-party cookies was leveraged by Google and other advertisers to maintain cookies outside of browser privacy settings... Obviously, there are many ways to force a browser to make requests to a third party in an attempt to set cookies: images,CSS files,JS, and so on.However this technique bypassed an explicit setting to block third party cookies by taking advantage of the behind the scenes for submission - form submission." Hacking Web Apps by Mike Shema.

Comment: Every request would pass with the correct cookie, and after the conversation with `Gumbo` i can say that 3rd party blocking has no effect at all on csrf requests. the request would pass with the cookie.